# Geolocate service I can use?

Tags: ip-address

I can access very accurate geolocate info from Google Analytics, but is there any way to access the geolocate information of Google or otherwise for an IP address, from a computer program, like a web ervice or something? I know there is "whois" but I would like something a little less hassle.

Comment: Obligatory XKCD link: http://xkcd.com/713/

Answer (score 3):

One of the best options I have found for doing this is [MaxMind city GeoIP data](http://www.maxmind.com/app/city). They have an [API](http://www.maxmind.com/app/web_services#city) and a free [lite version](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) you can get started with as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm which gives 20 IP lookups / hour.  Generally IP lookups are not so accurate (they map to the ISP), and most HTML5-capable browsers can read the location.

Comment: When I used this service, if the site owner forgot to pay for more look-ups, it would interject a page of their choosing every so often.  To me, that was much **much** worse than just not working.

Comment: Well a site-owner has to gauge how many requests will be needed, and pay for extra request as needed.  However that is pretty bad.